# How to active searching inner join in datatables with server-side?

Tags: php, datatable

I have some problem with server-side datatables. When data I use inner join the datatables not working, but if I use query `select * from table` this work. its datatables controler :

```html
<?php

require_once '../config/config.php'; // Use require. Can not use INCLUDE function
// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData = $_REQUEST;

$columns = array(
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 => 'id_hanca',
    1 => 'id_detail_po',
    2 => 'ukuran',
    3 => 'jumlah_hanca',
    4 => 'status_hanca',
    5 => 'id_user',
    6 => 'id_vendor'
);


// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * ";
$sql.=" FROM hanca";
$query = $db->query($sql);
$totalData = $query->num_rows;
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.

$sql = "SELECT
model.nm_model, hanca.id_hanca, hanca.ukuran, hanca.jumlah_hanca, user.name_usr, vendor.nama_vendor
FROM hanca
INNER JOIN po_detail ON po_detail.id_detail_po = hanca.id_detail_po
INNER JOIN model ON model.id_model = po_detail.id_model
INNER JOIN user ON user.id_usr = hanca.id_user
INNER JOIN vendor ON vendor.id_vendor = hanca.id_vendor WHERE 1=1";
if (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" AND ( po_detail LIKE '%" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' ";
    $sql.=" OR model LIKE '%" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' )";
}
$query = $db->query($sql);
$totalFiltered = $query->num_rows; // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY " . $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']] . " " . $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] . "  LIMIT " . $requestData['start'] . " ," . $requestData['length'] . "   ";

$query = $db->query($sql);

$data = array();
$no = 1;
foreach ($query as $row) {
     
    $nestedData = array();
    $nestedData[] = $no++;
    $nestedData[] = $row['nm_model'];
    $nestedData[] = $row['ukuran'];
    $nestedData[] = $row['jumlah_hanca'];
    $nestedData[] = $row['name_usr'];
    $nestedData[] = $row['nama_vendor'];
    // Input Hiddden to include value for update cart
    // Add html button for action
    $nestedData[] = "<a href='#' class=\" btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat\" onClick=\"detailBelanja('$row[id_hanca]');\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"Detail Belanja\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\"></span> Detail</a>";
    $data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
    "draw" => intval($requestData['draw']), // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
    "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData), // total number of records
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
    "data" => $data   // total data array
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

**this text dummy for required more detail**
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et arcu aliquet, congue metus eu, congue sapien. Nam suscipit efficitur elit, ac maximus felis tincidunt eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis porttitor risus sed erat dignissim varius

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Html & JS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = 0;
            $('#data_table').dataTable({
                "sServerMethod": "POST", 
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "get_data.php",

                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: ['pdf', 'csv'],
            });

            // To edit
            $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(id);
                // Editing code here
            });

            // To delete
            $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                if(confirm('Are you sure'))
                {
                    alert('Pending');
                    // deleting code here
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        .odd{
            background-color: #FFF8FB !important;
        }
        .even{
            background-color: #DDEBF8 !important;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <table id="data_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Expertise</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <!-- Dynamic Body -->
        </tbody>

    </table>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die('Connection Error');
mysql_select_db("testing_db") or die("Database Connection Error");

$start  = $_REQUEST['iDisplayStart'];
$length = $_REQUEST['iDisplayLength'];
$sSearch = $_REQUEST['sSearch'];

$col = $_REQUEST['iSortCol_0'];

$arr = array(0 => 't1.first_name',1 => 't1.last_name', 2 => 't1.email');

$sort_by = $arr[$col];
$sort_type = $_REQUEST['sSortDir_0'];

$position_filter = '';
$position = substr($_REQUEST['sSearch_3'], 1, -1);
if($position != '')
{
    $position_filter = "and t1.position LIKE '%".$position."%'";
}

$qry = "select t1.id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.email, t1.position, t1.office, t2.department, t3.expertise from datatables_demo t1 JOIN datatable_dept t2 ON t1.id = t2.emp_id JOIN datatable_expertise t3 ON t1.id = t3.emp_id where (first_name LIKE '%".$sSearch."%' or last_name LIKE '%".$sSearch."%' or email LIKE '%".$sSearch."%') ".$position_filter." ORDER BY ".$sort_by." ".$sort_type." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$length;    // join defined here

$res = mysql_query($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}

$qry = "select count(id) as count from datatables_demo";
$res = mysql_query($qry);

while($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $iTotal = $row['count'];
}

$rec = array(
    'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iTotal,
    'aaData' => array()
);

$k=0;
if (isset($data) && is_array($data)) {

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $rec['aaData'][$k] = array(
            0 => ucwords(strtolower($item['first_name'])),
            1 => ucwords(strtolower($item['last_name'])),
            2 => ucwords(strtolower($item['email'])),
            3 => ucwords(strtolower($item['position'])),
            4 => ucwords(strtolower($item['department'])),
            5 => ucwords(strtolower($item['expertise'])),
        );
        $k++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($rec);
?>
```

Comment: Any explanation what you did?

Comment: Its a server side data table with searching, sorting, pdf download, editing and deletion or record functionality in it.

Comment: @Pandey . after i think. i use datatables ver. 1.10.7 to all my project, so i think i should use my code on above, would u give me solution searching on inner join (not `select * from table`) by my code on above, please ?

Comment: Bro, download the code from here and make what changes you required. Its a working code.
https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing